# Phonegap calendar plugin on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

Trying to get the Calendar plugin for Phongegap to work. What I'm trying to do is to register the event when clicking on `event`. Also using Jquery Mobile.

Code:

```
        <title>Calendar</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ja/calendar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var cal;
            cal = window.plugins.calendarPlugin;

            $('#event').click(function() {
                              function createEvent(title,location,notes, startDate, endDate){
                              var title = document.getElementById=("eventTitle");
                              var notes = document.getElementById=("eventNotes");
                              var startDate = document.getElementById=("eventStart");
                              var endDate = document.getElementById=("eventEnd");
                              cal.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate);
                              }
                              });

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <body>
        Titel:<input type="text" id="eventTitle"><br>
            Anteckning:<input type="text" id="eventNotes"><br>
                Startdatum:<input type="date" id="eventStart"><br>
                    Slutdatum:<input type="date" id="eventEnd"><br>

        <button id="event">Create event</button>

                        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery to define the variables, I just completed a project like yours and my code looks like this:

```
        var title = $("#name").val();
        var location = $("#location").val()
        var notes = $("#notes").val();
        // getting dates using the moment.js file
        var s = $("#startDate").val();
        var startDate = moment(s).toDate();
        var e = $("#endDate").val();
        var endDate = moment(e).toDate();
```

The Date aspects of it are using something else to get the times as well as the date. But you see the basic format working here. Try that and let me know how it goes